# Help with removing element from list using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list:

```
<ul id="links_list" class="links_list">

<li id="296" class="sidebar_link">text
    <a onclick="deleteLink(296)" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete Link</a>
</li>

<li id="297" class="sidebar_link">text2
    <a onclick="deleteLink(297)" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete Link</a>
</li>

    ... etc for a long list of items ...

</ul>
```

I'm currently able to remove the first element using this:

```
function deleteFirst() {

... do ajax stuff ..

$('ul.links_list li:first-child').fadeTo("fast", 0.01, function(){ //fade
    $(this).slideUp("fast", function() { //slide up
        $(this).remove(); //then remove from the DOM
    });

});

}
```

How can I modify this function to allow me to delete any item in the list?

Comment: For anyone finding this in the future please do **not** use the accepted answer, `$("anything #id")` is a tremendously inefficient selector, and doesn't address any of the issues here.  An ID selector should be *only* `$("#ID")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$('ul.links_list li:first-child')` use `$('ul.links_list li#' + itemID)` and pass the itemID through the delete function.

Comment: You should never use an ID selector like that it should just be `$('#' + itemID)`.

Comment: Nick Craver is right, if using IDs there is no need to be so specific with the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I would bind all the links at once instead of inline, like this:

```
<ul id="links_list" class="links_list">
  <li data-id="296" class="sidebar_link">text
    <a href="#">Delete Link</a>
  </li>
  <li data-id="297" class="sidebar_link">text2
    <a href="#">Delete Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then script like this:

```
$('#links_list li a').click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("data-id");
  //do ajax stuff
  $(this).closest("li").fadeTo("fast", 0.01).slideUp("fast", function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent page scrolling with # href
});
```

This fixes a few issues and some improvements:

- IDs can't start with a number unless you're using HTML5
- Markup is much lighter (you can probably remove the classes too)
- [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) is a queued animation same as [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/), no need to use a callback for it
- The ID is gotten relatively, no more in-line script, easier to maintain and in another file

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YeBY4/).

Comment: "IDs can't start with a number unless you're using HTML5" Well yeah, but then you're using `data-id`, which is also HTML5, so erm... what was my point again? Never mind.

Comment: @YiJiang - data attributes don't interfere with HTML4, where as in numeric IDs are explicitly not allowed.  One is "just isn't in the spec yet" the other is specifically forbidden :)

Answer (score 0):

:nth-child Selector

See http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

For example :

```
$('ul.links_list li:nth-child(10)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your HTML to pass a reference to the one that was clicked, then use that reference.

HTML

```
<li id="296" class="sidebar_link">text
    <a onclick="deleteLink(this)" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete Link</a>
</li>
<li id="297" class="sidebar_link">text2
    <a onclick="deleteLink(this)" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete Link</a>
</li>
```

javascript

```
function deleteLink( elem ) {
    $( elem.parentNode ).fadeTo("fast", 0.01, function() { //fade
        $(this).slideUp("fast", function() { //slide up
            $(this).remove(); //then remove from the DOM
        });
    });
}​
```